# Nvidia Optimus + CUDA + bumblebee + 14.04

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee

I am the unfortunate to have laptop with optimus technology(nvidia gpu + intel integrated gpu), which seems to make a lot of problems to the new Ubutnu users.

I'm running fresh Ubuntu 14.04 install with Nvidia GPU: gtx 760m, and I want to install the following set: nvidia driver + bumblebee + CUDA 6.5 + Nsight Eclipse. I'm interested in running only few program on nvidia GPU via bumblebee and its $optirun command. The rest of the system I want to stay and run on the intel's GPU.

I've searched the whole internet on how to do that, and each search gave sometimes completely different, and sometimes slightly different answers. I followed some of them and each time I failed.

Nvidia driver:

- should I install the latest driver (340.46 [http://www.nvidia.pl/download/driver....aspx/78504/pl](http://www.nvidia.pl/download/driverResults.aspx/78504/pl)) and just run it? Or later driver?
- Should I install the driver via terminal ? Via Software&Updates ? Or maybe from another repository?
- Some users say to blacklist opensource nouveau driver. Some user say the installation process does it automatically. Lots of users end with the black screen problem

CUDA:

- some surces say to

sudo apt-get install nvidia-cuda-toolkit

- some say just

sudo apt-get install cuda

Could someone who DOES know the problem inside out, paste here the step by step solution? Which driver, from what source? How to verify each installation and step. It'd be helpful for every user struggling with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I've been having the same difficulty getting my GT 750m to be recognized by Ubuntu 14.04 and 14.10. After many different drivers, and many restarts, I came across this on the NVIDIA web site that might explain why some of us are having so much trouble:

> Note that the list of supported GPU products is provided to indicate
>   which GPUs are supported by a particular driver version. Some designs
>   incorporating supported GPUs may not be compatible with the NVIDIA
>   Linux driver: in particular, notebook and all-in-one desktop designs
>   with switchable (hybrid) or Optimus graphics will not work if means to
>   disable the integrated graphics in hardware are not available.
>   Hardware designs will vary from manufacturer to manufacturer, so
>   please consult with a system's manufacturer to determine whether that
>   particular system is compatible.

I have a Dell Inspiron 7537, and I've given up on getting the 750m to come to life on it.